# Access content in UITabBarController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a method that keeps track of the number of times a user clicks a button in a view controller that is part of a `UITabBarController`. I want to update the navigation title to display the number. I have the function set to update the title, but I can't seem to figure out how to access it from the 'child' view controller.

I did set up a delegate to be called whenever the button is pressed, but I don't know how to set the delegate to the tab bar controller.

How can I access the tab bar controller from within a 'child' view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `self.tabBarController`